# Where to declare interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code;

**App.tsx:**

```
interface IAppComponents {
  [key: string]: React.FC<IAppComponentProps>
}

interface IAppComponentProps {
  setAppDisplay: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
}

const APP_COMPONENTS : IAppComponents = {
  "MainMenu": MainMenu
}

function App() {
  const [appDisplay, setAppDisplay] = useState("MainMenu");
  const AppComponent = useMemo(() => APP_COMPONENTS[appDisplay], [appDisplay]);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {AppComponent ? (
        <AppComponent setAppDisplay={setAppDisplay} />
      ) : (
        "Invalid AppComponent"
      )}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

**MainMenu.tsx:**

```
interface IAppComponentProps {
  setAppDisplay: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
}

export default ({setAppDisplay} : IAppComponentProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      MainMenu
    </div>
  )
}
```

As you can see, I'm using IAppComponentProps in both files. Ideally I don't want to repeat myself, so what is the most accepted way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, you can `export` and `import` interfaces just like you can functions, classes, etc. So put the interface in a module (perhaps on its own, or perhaps grouped with other things like it), and:

```
import React from "react"; // Or whatever is appropriate for your project

export interface IAppComponentProps {
  setAppDisplay: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
}
```

Then in the modules that need it

```
import { IAppComponentProps } from "/path/to/the/module";
```